# Memory limit for mmap

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, mmap

I am trying to mmap a char device. It works for 65536 bytes. But I get the following error if I try for more memory.

> mmap: Resource temporarily unavailable

I want to mmap 1MB memory for a device. I use alloc_chrdev_region, cdev_init, cdev_add for the char device. How can I mmap memory larger than 65K? Should I use block device?

Answer (score 1):

Using the MAP_LOCKED flag in the mmap call can cause this error. The used mlock can return EAGAIN if the amount of memory can not be locked.

From `man mmap`:

> MAP_LOCKED (since Linux 2.5.37) Lock the pages of the mapped region
>   into memory in the manner of mlock(2). This flag is ignored in older
>   kernels.

From `man mlock`:

> EAGAIN: 
>   Some or all of the specified address range could not be
>   locked.

Answer (score -1):

Did you implement *somedevice_mmap()* file operation?

```
static int somedev_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    /* Do something. You probably need to use ioremap(). */

    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations somedev_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    /* Initialize other file operations. */
    .mmap  = somedev_mmap,
};
```

Comment: If .mmap() is not implemented, then ENODEV will be returned, rather than EAGAIN.

Comment: Yes. As I am saying it is working for 64K RAM. In the function I am calling remap_pfn_range. I am seeing no problem when registering the device. Only when opening from userspace program.

Comment: The source of the error code is your device drivers `somedev_mmap` method.  When do you return -EAGAIN?

Comment: @Roland I am getting a similar error. My implementation is same as you mentioned in your pseudo code. I am returning `EAGAIN` after the `remap_pfn_range` function .What exactly causes this error ?